# Why is React.Fragment causing the console error: Results Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
const MyField = class extends React.Component {
...
  renderField = (reduxFormFieldProps) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Form.Input />
      {!reduxFormFieldProps.meta.submitFailed ? null :
      <Form.Error />
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
  render = () => (
    <ReduxFormField
      type="text"
      component={this.renderField}
    />
  );
};
```

This is causing the error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

However, if I change `<React.Fragment>s` to `<div>s` it works fine... What am I doing wrong here with React.Fragment?

Comment: are you using React 16.2?

Comment: Yes... React.Fragment works in other parts of my app, just not in the above example for some reason. Id' like to learn why

Comment: reduxFormFieldProps is undefined  ? plz check..

Comment: it is... the above works fine if I use <DIV>s

Comment: What are `Form.Input` and `Form.Error` defined as?

Comment: Did you mean? `class MyField extends React.Component` 

Maybe not fixing anything but you could simplify the code to  `{reduxFormFieldProps.meta.submitFailed && <Form.Error />}`

Comment: @Kunukn I'm not following, would you mind posting an answer?

Comment: @sylvanaar Form... is a UI-Component form Semantic-UI-React

Comment: I'm also getting this warning with fragments, despite the page still rendering correctly.

Comment: @AnApprentice can you provide me a jsfiddle link or any other online link, so that I can understand it better?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really simple.

Since <React.Fragment> is used for wrapping up components and elements without creating any new DOM node when returning.

The attribute 'component' of ReduxFormField requires one single DOM node but function 'renderField' actually returns 2 elements which causes problems here.